# command line language for Android tablet (wget equivalent)

Tags: applications, internal-storage

I am a Linux enthusiast and probable expert, and using it since 1993 on the command line (today with [zsh](https://zsh.org/)) (and Unix since 1987, SunOS3.2).

I personally have a Huawei tablet, details [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/216710/305984). With an SD card.

I also have a Logitech Bluetooth keyboard case for that tablet.

I need to be able to read some PDF documents on the tablet without a working internet connection. (at my work at [CEA/LIST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CEA-LIST:_Laboratory_for_Integration_of_Systems_and_Technology) - a quite bureaucratic organization since indirectly related to French nuclear warheads, I have a powerful Dell workstation with `root` access & Ethernet connection to the Internet under Debian/Unstable - so sometimes Xorg does not work properly -, but no access to the corporate Wifi; for the [clips-rule-gcc](https://github.com/bstarynk/clips-rules-gcc) project I prefer to read the [CLIPS](http://www.clipsrules.net/) documentation on my [BYOD](https://whatis.techtarget.com/definition/BYOD-bring-your-own-device) tablet).

If my tablet was good genuine Linux [Debian](https://debian.org/) system, I would just `wget http://clipsrules.sourceforge.net/documentation/v640/bpg.pdf` when Internet is available, and later `evince bpg.pdf` when it is not, taking advantage of `zsh` auto completion facilities.

What are the equivalent on Android 8 ?

My AppStore is google, and I was not yet able to root my tablet. Dreaming of that every day.

Comment: Depending on your device/ROM, it ships with either `toolbox`, `toybox` or `busybox`. At least the latter usually ships with `wget`, which you then could use either directly (`wget ..`) or indirectly (`busybox wget ..`); you can try the same with `toolbox` if available, but that and `toybox` usually don't have `wget`. Last resort would be installing a busybox app from your favorite store. As for PDF readers, [there are plenty](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/office_pdf).

Comment: I am veryu unfamiliar with Android. busybox don't work without root access. rootchecker costs me 3.5€. Can I avoid that?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch busybox or any static built binaries work perfectly on non-rooted Android. Use with `adb shell` or any terminal emulator app. Termux is a good one.

Comment: adb push busybox /data/local/tmp

Comment: i don't fully understand the question is about cmd line or app recommendation, why don't you just install any pdf viewer (like OfficeSuite) you can even open pdf from cmd line if this is requirement

Answer (score 2):

Did you tried [Termux](https://termux.com/)?
The terminal emulator for android, this does not require any root access either.

[image]

Edit: to install `wget` type `pkg install wget` and press enter.

For pdf viewer use native android one such as [Mu Pdf](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.artifex.mupdfdemo) or, [Google pdf viewer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.pdfviewer)

Once installed you can try `xdg-open filename.pdf`
It will give you a list of the compatible app to open the file or else you can open the pdf viewer app to browse files of your choice.

Comment: Thanks. `apt install evince` fails after installing package x11-repo

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch use a commandline PDF reader or GUI Android app. X-server is not native to Android, so is always troublesome. You need to install additional XServer or VNC app and configure x-11 to work with them.

Comment: But which one? I never used Android before this year

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch See my link above (comment on your question). I use MuPDF and am quite happy with it. // **digiwizkid:** could you please [edit] your answer and include the details on wget etc? Just installing Termux doesn't solve the problem. I guess it either comes with `wget` (in that case say so), or one must `apt install` it (then that should be pointed out). While on it, maybe integrate the details from your comment as well?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I have edited my answer, please check. If this answers your question please accept it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

the android cmd line language is MirBSD Korn Shell [mksh](http://www.mirbsd.org/mksh.htm) and default core utilities are FreeBSD or [toybox](http://www.landley.net/toybox) (and few android specific toolbox) applets

there is no dpkg or apt equivalent the closest is android package manager (commands `am` or `pm`)

default console is android debug bridge (like ssh) you need to enable usb-debugging in developer settings, connect to pc and install package `android-tools-adb` then you can start `adb shell` and authorize the ~/. android RSA-key by simply accept confirmation dialog on tablet

Comment: `am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d file://bpg.pdf`